# How do I move my working directory using TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit, working-directory

I've got my working directories for a couple of projects in one folder on my hard drive, and I want to move them to another folder. I'm fairly inexperienced with Git and TortoiseGit, so I don't know whether I can just drag and drop them or make a copy and then delete the original without anything happening in the repo. I've done some searching, but most of what I've found refers to moving files within the working copy, not moving the working copy itself.

I've done half of the move already: I've created a new folder and cloned a copy of the project, but I've still got the original working copy, which TortoiseGit is still showing as being under version control. Is there a way to make Git forget about the original copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything related to the Git history is stored in the `.git` folder.

[image]

For example in the screenshot below, I can copy `git-test` to `another-folder` and, as long as I move everything in `git-test`, TortoiseGit will continue to operate as before.
[image]

To make Git forget about version control in a folder, simply delete the `.git` folder. As you can see in the screenshot below, when I did that in `another-folder`, the icons are gone indicating that it's just a normal folder now.

[image]